# Populate Context Menu from QTableView Cell DisplayRole

Tags: python, pyside, qtableview

How would I populate the context menu action 'Search:' with the display text from the cell which was right-clicked in the QTableView. Ideally i would like the Menu item to show the text of the cell. In this example it would say 'Search: 45' and if the user clicks the action it would set the text of the QLineEdit.

[image]

```
import sys
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui


class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Example, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # controls
        model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(5, 3)
        model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['NAME', 'AGE', 'CAREER'])

        people = [
            {'name': 'Kevin', 'age': 5, 'career': 'athlete'},
            {'name': 'Maggie', 'age': 13, 'career': 'banker'},
            {'name': 'Leslie', 'age': 32, 'career': 'banker'},
            {'name': 'Emily', 'age': 45, 'career': 'athlete'},
            {'name': 'David', 'age': 27, 'career': 'banker'},
            {'name': 'Marie', 'age': 63, 'career': 'secretary'}
        ]
        for row, obj in enumerate(people):
            item = QtGui.QStandardItem(obj['name'])
            model.setItem(row, 0, item)

            item = QtGui.QStandardItem(str(obj['age']))
            model.setItem(row, 1, item)

            item = QtGui.QStandardItem(obj['career'])
            model.setItem(row, 2, item)

        proxy_model = QtGui.QSortFilterProxyModel()
        proxy_model.setSourceModel(model)

        # controls
        self.ui_table = QtGui.QTableView()
        self.ui_table.setEditTriggers(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.ui_table.setSelectionBehavior(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
        self.ui_table.setSelectionMode(QtGui.QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection)
        self.ui_table.setModel(proxy_model)
        self.ui_table.setContextMenuPolicy(QtCore.Qt.CustomContextMenu)

        self.ui_search = QtGui.QLineEdit()

        # actions
        self.act_search_keyword = QtGui.QAction('Search:', self)

        # menu
        self.context_menu = QtGui.QMenu('File')
        self.context_menu.addAction(self.act_search_keyword)


        # lay main
        lay_main = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        lay_main.addWidget(self.ui_search)
        lay_main.addWidget(self.ui_table)
        self.setLayout(lay_main)

        # connections
        self.ui_table.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.open_context_menu)


    def open_context_menu(self, point):
        self.context_menu.exec_(QtGui.QCursor.pos())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create the menu in the slot and use the position to obtain the data through `indexAt()` that returns the `QModelIndex`

```
    ...
    self.ui_search = QtGui.QLineEdit()

    # lay main
    lay_main = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
    lay_main.addWidget(self.ui_search)
    lay_main.addWidget(self.ui_table)
    self.setLayout(lay_main)

    # connections
    self.ui_table.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.open_context_menu)

def open_context_menu(self, point):
    context_menu = QtGui.QMenu()
    ix = self.ui_table.indexAt(point)
    val = ix.data()
    context_menu.addAction("Search: {}".format(val))
    action = context_menu.exec_(self.ui_table.mapToGlobal(point))
    if action:
        self.ui_search.setText(val)
```